Why does Layout.verticalStretchFactor or Layout.horizontalStretchFactor not work?
As the official document says, there are two attached properties since Qt 6.5, Layout.verticalStretchFactor and Layout.horizontalStretchFactor, which allow you to specify the vertical and horizontal stretch factor. For example, if the first item has a stretch factor of 1 and the second item has a stretch factor of 2, the first item will aim to get 1/3 of the available space, and the second will aim to get 2/3 of the available space.
However, I had a try and did not get the expected result. The two items had the same size. Here is the code:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.verticalStretchFactor: 1
            border.color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.verticalStretchFactor: 2
            border.color: "blue"
        }
    }
}

The same problem for Layout.horizontalStretchFactor. I am using Qt 6.7.2. Is there anything wrong?

Sounds like a bug. That works but only if you set Layout.preferredHeight and Layout.maximumHeight to some values.
As a workaround you can set it to:
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 0
    Rectangle {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredHeight: 1
        Layout.maximumHeight: 1000
        Layout.verticalStretchFactor: 1
        color: "red"
    }
    
    Rectangle {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.preferredHeight: 1
        Layout.maximumHeight: 1000
        Layout.verticalStretchFactor:2
        color: "blue"
    }
}


Thank you @folibis. I tried as you suggested, and now the two items had different sizes. However, the height ratio between the first and the second rectangle seemed to be 1:4, not 1:2 as that of verticalStretchFactor. If I set the first verticalStretchFactor to 1, and the second to 5, then the height ratio was about 1:12.8. I don't know why.
